# Consciousness as sufficient complexity

Tags: consciousness

First of all, let me state that I am a newcomer to cognitive science in general and this community in particular, so feel free to chew me out if this question is inappropriate in some way.

I have always thought that the definition of consciousness was a question of complexity. In particular, a network would be considered conscious if and only if it had at least as many nodes and connections as the human brain.

I have two sub-questions regarding this definition:

- Is there anyone in the literature who espouses this point of view? Is this point of view generally respected among cognitive scientists?
- What are the potential problems with this definition as it relates to other definitions in cognitive science?